# How to remove shadow on image with css

Tags: css

I am trying to remove the shadow on images. I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
.img none { border:none!important; }
```

http://www.101calendartemplates.com/watercolor-calendar/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the shadows by using this:

```
img  {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Do you control the CSS at all? Because there is a class `alignnone` applying those shadows. If you control the CSS just change that class to not apply [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow). If not and you are trying to insert some CSS for it you can use the above.

The above will apply to all img elements. If you want to only apply it to the images with that `alignnone` class that is adding the shadow in the first place you can just override like this:

```
.alignnone  {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Just for reference this is what the class adding the shadows looks like:

```
.alignnone {
    border: #b9b9b9 solid 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

As another side note the CSS you tried is not really correct.

```
.img none { border:none!important; }
```

This says there is an element with the class `img` who has a descendant element of type `none`. `none` is not a valid HTML tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the class "none" to the images that read "customize & print". I only want to remove the shadow from those images and leave it on the other images.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. Good luck. And feel free to accept this as the answer if you feel it helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly set the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property to not appear :

```
/* The important tag is optional but will supercede any other styles that might add it */
img {
    box-shadow: none!important;
    /* Browser specific implementations */
    -moz-box-shadow: none!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I believe you may have the declaration confused.

I believe it should be `img .none { border:none!important; }`

Use web inspector on the image in chrome or firefox and investigate the properties. It may have outline or box shadow enabled.

Below should cover all the basics, but its important to only apply the rules needed for your desired styling.

```
img .none { 
    border: none !important; 
    outline: none !important; 
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I think that it should be box-shadow since that is what I used to create the shadow. I am just trying to remove the shadow on some of the images (those that read "customize & print"                                          .img none alignnone {
 box-shadow: none !important;
}



.alignnone {
    border: #b9b9b9 solid 1px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}